# physical screen size acquired by GetDeviceCaps is not the actual physical size of my screen

Tags: c++, winapi

Under Windows 7, I use the following code to get the physical width in mm of screen. The 'hSize' is 482 which is much larger than the actual size which is about 310 (measured with ruler). Why is that?

```
HDC screen = GetDC(NULL);
int hSize=GetDeviceCaps(screen,HORZSIZE);
```

PS: I need DPI value to render maps.

Comment: The value returned for `HORZSIZE` is an approximation, based on the configured DPI and the number of pixels. It's meant to be a logical measurement, not a physical one. It can be off by quite an amount, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: What @MarkRansom said (I'm just AOL-ing).

Comment: If you need the DPI, just ask for it: `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY` are documented as giving you those values. (Unless I'm wrong, in which case feel free to correct me.)

Comment: Sorry ,AOL-ing? @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: @ShaoboZi: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/AOL-.html

Comment: @andlabs I need - 'pixel per mm' which will be used to rendering maps. And I can use DPI directly get from winapi. The DPI get here may not fit into the map rendering system ,  which I am worrying about.

Comment: You can go from pixels per inch to pixels per mm with some basic arithmetic and the conversion factor between inches and mm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the comments indicate `GetDeviceCaps(HORSIZE/VERTSIZE)` is notoriously inaccurate. It's always been that way, and it will probably always be that way. There's nothing you can do about it, so you'll just have to pretend this API doesn't exist and move on. It won't help you find the real size of the monitor. You'd be better off just assuming a fixed default and letting the user adjust the dimensions manually if necessary.

Fortunately someone has already done there research and figured out a better way to find the physical size of a display on Windows. In a blog entry entitled [Reading Monitor Physical Dimensions, or: Getting the EDID, the Right Way](http://ofekshilon.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/) Ofek describes how you can get more accurate dimensions from the montior's [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) by using Windows' SetupAPI. The outline of the procedure is described as follows:

> 1. Call `SetupDiGetClassDevsEx` to get an `HDEVINFO` handle.
> 2. Use this `HDEVINFO` in a call to `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` to populate an `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` struct.
> 3. Use both `HDEVICE` and `HDEVINFO` in a call to `SetupDiOpenDevRegKey`, to finally get an `HKEY` to the desired registry key – the one that
>    holds the EDID block.

The linked blog entry contains sample code, and information about other alternative methods he tried.

Note that even EDID isn't always going to be accurate. While it's what the monitor itself says are its own dimensions, there's still plenty of opportunity for error. A vendor can easily make a mistake with the dimensions in the EDID and the monitor would still work perfectly, so there's little incentive to get these values right.

Comment: Just hope you don't need to do this on a multi-monitor system! I once had a monitor whose EDID was so far off that it didn't even properly provide its native resolution: http://superuser.com/questions/713487/getting-proper-resolution-with-windows-7-and-older-monitor

Comment: The author the blog entry has another article on how to retrieve the EDID of a specific monitor in a multi-monitor system: http://ofekshilon.com/2014/06/19/reading-specific-monitor-dimensions/